# Is there any way to transform MSAccess .BAK into MySQL in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, mysql

My client wants to change application from MSAccess into Linux base with PHP/Mysql.

I got big file which is .BAK or (Binary (application/octet-stream)). I learnt it is backup file of MSAccess.

I am using Ubuntu and never had idea of Microsoft MSAccess. It would be very helpful if there is way to convert .BAK backup into MySQL.

All I want is MySQL which can be easily imported into Mysql.